# android expandable list view get view of group from child onclick listener

Tags: android, textview, expandablelistview

i have a expandable list view in my app, each group has a textview say T having dynamic value and each group has a single child within it. I want to refer to that T textview object of that Group whose child has been clicked on so that i can change the value of T accordingly as per the child item clicked.

I can easily get the TextView Object in case of groupClickListener but iam not able to get in case of childClickListener... pls see both here.

mExpandableListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                int groupPosition, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            TextView moreTextView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.group_more);  // this works fine

            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

mExpandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            boolean isExpanded=false;
            if(groupStatus[groupPosition]==1)
            {
                isExpanded=true;
            }
            View v1 = parent.getExpandableListAdapter().getGroupView(groupPosition, isExpanded, v, parent);
            TextView moreTextView = (TextView)v1.findViewById(R.id.group_more);  // doesn,t work as v1 is null all the times
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: please show what you have done

Answer (score 4):

```
// Listview on child click listener
expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
            int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(
                getApplicationContext(),
                listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)
                        + " : "
                        + listDataChild.get(
                                listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(
                                childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        return false;
    }
});
```

I hope its useful for you.

Comment: how will i get the reference to TextView object from this,and what is listDataChild here.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `getExpandableListAdapter()` on the "parent" and define your custom classes accordingly.
Then modify the values within the custom objects - the ExpandableListView will update automatically.
E.g.:

```
@Override
public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView _parent, View _v,
        int _groupPosition, int _childPosition, long _id
) {
    // do required casts for your custom objects for groups and childs.
    // In my case, I'm using class "Group"
    Group group=(Group)parent.getExpandableListAdapter().getGroup(_groupPosition);
    // In my case, I'm using class "Child"
    Child item=(Child)optionsList.getExpandableListAdapter().getChild(_groupPosition, _childPosition);
    // In my custom Group class, I've defined a field that populates a different
    // TextView within the Group layout - so, getter/setter method for "selection" were defined.
    // The ExpandableListView will be updated automatically based on the adapter updates.
    group.setSelection(item.getName());
    return true;
}
```

Not exactly sure why this happens - it seems like the ExpandableAdapter is tracking changes to the model itself... I don't have time to check the details on this.. but it works.